# A put option and a call option with identical exercise price are both marketable or neither is.

Tags: finance, economics, discrete-time

I am doing Exercise 1.13 in *Introduction to Mathematical Finance: Discrete Time Models* by Pliska.

**Exercise 1.13** Suppose the interest rate $r$ is a scalar, and let $c$ and $p$ denote the prices of a call and put, respectively, both having the same exercise price $e$. Show that either both are marketable or neither is marketable. Use risk neutral evaluation to show that the former case one has
$$c-p=S_0-e/(1+r).$$

The parity at last is reached by book-keeping calculation. However, I don't know how to show the simultaneous marketability of call/put option with same exercise price. Could anyone hint me? Thanks in advance!

Here, marketable means:
There exists some trading strategy $H$ such that $H$ generates $X$, i.e., the $t=1$ value of portfolio $V_1=X$.

Comment: Not sure the information is complete.  What's a "trading strategy"?  Specifically, what instruments are available for trading?  Can you, say, buy or sell a forward position in the underlying asset?  Can you at least go long or short the underlying asset?  Can you borrow cash at the riskless rate?  If you sell short, can you earn the riskless rate on the proceeds of the short sale?

Comment: try constructing the hedge portfolio?